# How to include JNDI context file into spring-boot embedded container

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, jndi, embedded-container

I have a context file which contains a JNDI datasource information as follows

```
    <Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/myapp" auth="${auth.myapp}" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="${maxActive.myapp}"
              maxIdle="${maxIdle.myapp}"
              maxWait="${maxWait.myapp}"
              username="${username.myapp}"
              password="${password.myapp}"
              driverClassName="${driverClassName.myapp}"
              url="${url.myapp}"
              validationQuery="${validationQuery.myapp}"
              factory="com.myapp.MyDataSourceFactory"/>
</Context>
```

I have multiple datasource resource similar to the above. I am migrationg my spring MVC application to spring-boot. But my application is not recognizing this context file.

I am using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE

How to configure my spring-boot application to use this context file? Now I am getting the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```